# Dictionary saving last result to every value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently in the process of making a web crawler using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. I am using a for loop to create a list of dictionaries with the values being the `href` of the `a` tags. I am having issues doing this however since all of the results will be the last `href` on that page. Here is the output when I print out the final result:

```
[{'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}, {'link': '/terms'}]
```

I am unsure as to why it's doing the last value only. I assume it's because through the last loop, it assigns all keys with the same name to that value. How can I go around fixing this? Here is the code.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tags_dict = {}
tags_list = []

r = requests.get("http://chicosadventures.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    tags_dict['link'] = link.get('href')
    tags_list.append(tags_dict)

dump = json.dumps(tags_list)
print(dump)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with `tags_dict`. You are just storing a reference to that **one** dictionary again and again in your list, and since its a reference, the last value gets reflected in all entries. I changed it to create a new dict object for each iteration, now it works fine

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tags_list = []
r = requests.get("http://chicosadventures.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    tags_list.append({"link": link.get('href')})

dump = json.dumps(tags_list)
print(dump)
```

Output:

> [{"link": "/"}, {"link": "/about_chico"}, {"link":
>   "/about_the_author"}, {"link": "/about_the_illustrator"}, {"link":
>   "/chico_in_the_news_"}, {"link": "/order_your_copy"}, {"link":
>   "/contact_us"}, {"link": "/about_chico"}, {"link":
>   "/about_the_author"}, {"link": "/about_the_illustrator"}, {"link":
>   "/chico_in_the_news_"}, {"link": "/order_your_copy"}, {"link":
>   "/contact_us"}, {"link": "/privacy"}, {"link": "javascript:print()"},
>   {"link": "http://www.ebtech.net/"}, {"link": "/terms"}]